# What are the NVL and the NVL2 functions in Oracle? How do they differ?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for the detail answer with simple examples of these functions.

Comment: Tag the dbms. Those functions are product specific.

Comment: Sorry to be blunt, but literally the first result of Google search for `nvl vs nvl2` contains the answer. At least for me, that is...

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions131.htm#SQLRF00684 and https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions132.htm#SQLRF00685

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**NVL** checks if first argument is null and returns second argument:

```
select nvl(null, 'arg2') from dual
```

in this example result will be: arg2;

```
select nvl('arg1', 'arg2') from dual
```

and in this one: arg1;

**NVL2** has different logic. If first argument is not null then NVL2 returns second argument, but in other case it will return third argument:

```
select nvl2('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3') from dual
```

Result: arg2

```
select nvl2(null, 'arg2', 'arg3') from dual
```

Result: arg3

Comment: Note that if `argN` are expressions, then `select nvl2(arg1, arg2, arg3) from dual` will only return `arg3` if `arg1` evaluates to `null` AND if `arg2` can be evaluated. It seems to me that `nvl2` evaluates all three arguments no matter what. This is why I prefer to use `decode` which will only evaluate the necessary arguments.

Comment: In other words:
Bad:
`select nvl2(mydate, to_date(mydate || ' 23', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'), sysdate + 10000)  from (select null as mydate from dual);
select nvl2(mydate, to_date(mydate || ' 23', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'), sysdate + 10000)  from (select sysdate as mydate from dual);`
Good:
`select decode(mydate, null, sysdate + 10000, to_date(mydate || ' 23', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'))  from (select null as mydate from dual);
select decode(mydate, null, sysdate + 10000, to_date(mydate || ' 23', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24'))  from (select sysdate as mydate from dual);`

Answer (score 1):

Both the NVL(exp1, exp2) and NVL2(exp1, exp2, exp3) functions check the value exp1 to see if it is null.

With the NVL(exp1, exp2) function, if exp1 is not null, then the value of exp1 is returned; otherwise, the value of exp2 is returned, but case to the same data type as that of exp1.

With the NVL2(exp1, exp2, exp3) function, if exp1 is not null, then exp2 is returned; otherwise, the value of exp3 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

`Nvl(arg1,arg2) nvl` is used for converting null values.
In nvl if argument 1 is null then it returns argument 2 but argument 1 is not null it returns itself.
In `nvl2 (arg1,arg2,arg3)` in nvl2 it converts any number into according to given number with null also .
If arg 1 that's given number is null then it returns arg3
And on the other hand if it is not null it returns argument 2